# Passing textfield data between views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created two Views, each with four textfields. I have a switch that allows me to toggle back and forth between these two Views. When the switch is activated/deactivated, it passes the current textfield data to the destination ViewController and vice versa.

The following code worked fine initially. If I enter data in three textfields, say, in FirstViewController, I pressed the switch, the data appears in the corresponding three textfields of SecondViewController. If I press the switch again, data from the same three textfields will populate the corresponding textfields in FirstViewController.

After adding some more Views, labels, buttons, etc. that are not related to these specific textfields and switch, now the code no longer works and I can't figure out why. Only the last entered textfield data is passed to the destination, so if I enter data in three textfields, only the last entered one is passed. And if I toggle the switch again, now no data is passed.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction as to why this code worked initially, but now does not? Thank you.

FirstViewController.h

> ```
> import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>
> @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
>
> //Defines input value for each of the four textfields
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldA;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldB;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldC;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldD;
>
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldAContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldBContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldCContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldDContent;
>
> @end
> ```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize textFieldA;
@synthesize textFieldB;
@synthesize textFieldC;
@synthesize textFieldD;
@synthesize textFieldAContent;
@synthesize textFieldBContent;
@synthesize textFieldCContent;
@synthesize textFieldDContent;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textFieldA.text = self.textFieldAContent;
    self.textFieldB.text = self.textFieldBContent;
    self.textFieldC.text = self.textFieldCContent;
    self.textFieldD.text = self.textFieldDContent;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstToSecondView"])
    {
        SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.textFieldAContent = self.textFieldA.text;
        controller.textFieldBContent = self.textFieldB.text;
        controller.textFieldCContent = self.textFieldC.text;
        controller.textFieldDContent = self.textFieldD.text;
    }
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

> ```
> import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>
> @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
>
> //Defines input value for each of the four textfields
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldA;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldB;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldC;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldD;
>
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldAContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldBContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldCContent;
> @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldDContent;
>
> @end
> ```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize textFieldA;
@synthesize textFieldB;
@synthesize textFieldC;
@synthesize textFieldD;
@synthesize textFieldAContent;
@synthesize textFieldBContent;
@synthesize textFieldCContent;
@synthesize textFieldDContent;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textFieldA.text = self.textFieldAContent;
    self.textFieldB.text = self.textFieldBContent;
    self.textFieldC.text = self.textFieldCContent;
    self.textFieldD.text = self.textFieldDContent;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondToFirstView"])
    {
        FirstViewController *controller = (FirstViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.textFieldAContent = self.textFieldA.text;
        controller.textFieldBContent = self.textFieldB.text;
        controller.textFieldCContent = self.textFieldC.text;
        controller.textFieldDContent = self.textFieldD.text;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you clarify the "storyboard"? You seems to have 2 ViewController in ONE storyboard, and your added elements in each ones. But you keep saying that you have many Storyboard.

Comment: Hi Larme. I'm sorry, I used the wrong term. You are right, one storyboard and 2 ViewControllers. (When I typed the original post, I mistakenly thought the individual panels are called storyboards). I'll edit my post. Thanks.

Comment: It was working, and now it's not... are your segue identifiers still "SecondToFirstView" / "FirstToSecondView?"  If those got trashed in your storyboard edits, you'll still seque, but you'll be missing your property setter calls.  Also, unrelated:  You don't need @synthesize here.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but you shouldn't go back and forth with segues. When you think you're going back to FirstViewController, you're actually creating a new instance of that controller, so as you go back and forth, you will be adding more and more controllers, and none of them will ever be deallocated. When you go backwards, you either need to use an unwind segue, or use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: 
(assuming that you're using modals segues -- if you're using push segues, then use popViewControllerAnimated:).

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my question. I never figured out what the problem was, but as user redelmar commented to the original post, I shouldn't go back and forth with segues (the memory usage goes up every time I transition views). Instead, I did everything I intended to do on one ViewController. Thanks for all your help!